# Email intent crashes

Tags: java, android, email

I am new to email in android and I have followed examples found elsewhere, but my app crashes on:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"feedback@something.com"});
    emailBody="Myemail";
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send email..."));
```

Logcat:

```
01-01 14:09:54.596: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(642): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 14:09:54.596: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(642):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
```

Comment: You have this activity defined in AndroidManifest.xml right? If so, are you using anything like Tabhost or something like that?

Comment: I call a second activity from my main, which instantiates a class (of type Application) that is supposed to give user the chance to send an email. Dont know what Tabhost is. Manifest is all fine: application class gets called as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

instead of:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

See what happens. It works for me fine. Hopefully it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
I.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody);
```

Comment: unchanged. crashes with the same logcat

Comment: I am afraid i do not know then, sorry.